# No license information when applying OSS Review Toolkit (ORT) to golang project with GoMod package manager

Tags: go

I want to use ORT to get an overview of all licenses of third-party packages in my go project.

However, the generated analyzer-result.yml doesn't contain license information:

```
declared_licenses: []
```

Code example:
I have built ort docker image from https://github.com/oss-review-toolkit/ort
and use the following project as an example:

https://github.com/oss-review-toolkit/ort/tree/main/analyzer/src/funTest/assets/projects/synthetic/gomod

then run ort analysis via:

```
docker run -v $PWD/:/project ort --info analyze -i /project -o /project/ort/analyzer
```

How do I get the license information in my analysis result file?

Thanks for your help!